# Error when calling PHP file_get_contents function

Tags: php, html

`file_get_contents($file)` function must be executed in order to get html encoded file after that.

Function crashes returning

> failed to open stream: Invalid argument

However, if I set a text string (containing path) instead of variable call, it works. If I check variable content seems that is properly set before crashing.

Comment: What does var_dump($file) say?

Comment: you can check if file exists before call `file_get_contents` function. Just call `file_exists($file)` function and it will return TRUE if it exists.

Comment: is_file can be a better way to check if something is a file because file_exists returns true for directories as well as regular files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$filePath = '/complete/path/to/file.html';
if(is_file($filePath))
{
  $fileContents = file_get_contents($filePath);
  echo $fileContents; // echo out file contents
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to cast $file as string: `file_get_contents((string)$file);`